# Create a Bitmap/Drawable from file path

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to create a Bitmap or Drawable from existing file path.

```
String path = intent.getStringExtra("FilePath");
BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

mImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
// mImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, option));
// mImg.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
mImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mText.setText(path);
```

But `setImageBitmap()`, `setImageDrawable()` doesn't show an image from the path. I've printed path with `mText` and it looks like : `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100LGDSC/CAM00001.jpg`

What am i doing wrong? Anyone can help me?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) --> does this return an Bitmap object for you ? can you verify it ?

Comment: @autobot_101 in debug mode, it has `id` in `mBuffer`.  But its `mHeight`, `mWidth` value is `-1`, and `mLayoutBounds` is `null`.

Comment: Then you should check your file path again, because that means your image has not been 'inflated' to the bitmap object. Maybe you can try another image

Comment: @autobot_101 actually i got this image path from `Cursor` and tried other images, but same result. Also, i checked the path via `adb shell` and found out images are exists in that path.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Create bitmap from file path:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sd+filePath, imageName);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If you want to scale the bitmap to the parent's height and width then use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` function.

I think you are giving the wrong file path.

Comment: I already got my solution long time ago, but I'll take this as a correct answer because it can also handles OOM errors while you're loading a big scale image. Very clean and nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: I assume imageName here is any string? or is it any specific imageName?

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary Yes imageName could be any final String as the name of the image.

Answer (score 71):

It works for me:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

**Edit:**

If above hard-coded sdcard directory is not working in your case, you can fetch the sdcard path:

```
String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File imgFile = new  File(sdcardPath);
```

Comment: Try getting SdCard path from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` and then try

Answer (score 51):

here is a solution:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

Comment: I was searching for it!

Answer (score 3):

Well, using the static `Drawable.createFromPath(String pathName)` seems a bit more straightforward to me than decoding it yourself... :-)

If your `mImg` is a simple `ImageView`, you don't even need it, use `mImg.setImageUri(Uri uri)` directly.

Answer (score 2):

For Drawable -

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(your path in string);
```

For Bitmap -

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(your path in string);
```

#### How simple it was hope you like

Answer (score 1):

```
static ArrayList< Drawable>  d;
d = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
for(int i=0;i<MainActivity.FilePathStrings1.size();i++) {
  myDrawable =  Drawable.createFromPath(MainActivity.FilePathStrings1.get(i));
  d.add(myDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Note that you should explain the code that you provide in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access your drawables via a path, so if you want a human readable interface with your drawables that you can build programatically.

declare a HashMap somewhere in your class:

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> images = null;

//Then initialize it in your constructor:

public myClass() {
  if (images == null) {
    images = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    images.put("Human1Arm", R.drawable.human_one_arm);
    // for all your images - don't worry, this is really fast and will only happen once
  }
}
```

Now for access -

```
String drawable = "wrench";
// fill in this value however you want, but in the end you want Human1Arm etc
// access is fast and easy:
Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images.get(drawable));
canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
Log.d("OLOLOLO",Integer.toString(wrench.getHeight()));
canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);
```