# BitmapDrawable cannot decode

Tags: android

I'm working to create a health bar for a game and its failing: Thanks in advance!

```
    //there a corresponding ImageView in the layout
    healthLevel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.healthbar);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), "res/drawable/health.png");

    //vertical bar cropped from top
    clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(bitmapDrawable, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);  
    healthLevel.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable);

    HelperClass.setHealth();
    clipDrawable.setLevel(10000);
    clipDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

Log:

```
11-12 19:32:46.272: W/BitmapDrawable(10524): BitmapDrawable cannot decode res/drawable/health.png
```

Solution:

```
    //there a corresponding ImageView in the layout
    healthLevel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.healthbar);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.health);

    //Convert Bitmap to Drawable
    Drawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp); 

    //vertical bar cropped from top
    clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(bitmapDrawable, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);  
    healthLevel.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable);

    HelperClass.setHealth();
    clipDrawable.setLevel(10000);
    clipDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

Comment: do you need a `BitmapDrawable`? Can't you just use a Bitmap or a Drawable?

Comment: I don't know... I'm new to this so i'm just going off others i've found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your question, creating a `BitmapDrawable` from a file path needs **the file's absolute storage path** rather than the relative path of your app package.

I've tried the following pieces of code and it works.

```
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/ic_launcher.png");
    BitmapDrawable bw = new BitmapDrawable(file.getAbsolutePath());
    iv.setImageDrawable(bw);
```

However, i think that what you need is something like a `Bitmap` which can be created with

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You might find [this toturial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16804404/1929093) helpful.