# Bitmap to Base64 String

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, encode

I was trying the following code to encode a bitmap into a base64 string, but I always get wrong encoding.

By the way, `filePath` is an image file path.

```
public String encode(String filePath) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

How do I know if I get a wrong encoding? I use this website:

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: check that you giving right path for image otherwise code is looking fine.

Comment: the path to the image is right i checked it. i dont know what is wrong

Comment: You could tray `Base64.NO_PADDING` instead of / orred to `DEFAULT`, that is without trailing `=`s.

Answer (score 3):

Try this  code it  does proper encoding for me. Hope it may be help you.

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encodedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @kdeogharkar pointing out, your code is looking fine.

First, check if you have a right file path. Then check if you need a permission when accessing external file.

For handling OOM while we loading a big scale image, we can use:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sd+filePath, imageName);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
```

Then use the following decoding and encoding method:

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}
```

Example usage:

```
String myBase64Image = encodeToBase64(myBitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100);
Bitmap myBitmapAgain = decodeBase64(myBase64Image);
```

**NOTE**
this answer is mixed from:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28351881/4758255
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768973/4758255

Answer (score 1):

try to use NO_WRAP instead of DEFAULT

```
String stringEncode = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return stringEncode;
```

And use this [online tool](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) to convert base64 string (`stringEncode`) to image . If it is able to generate image your base64 string is correct.

Comment: what is option configuration while reading file path . Is it ARGB_8888 ? @Ofek

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String getImageEncodedData(String path) {
       File f = new File(path);
       Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
       try {
           imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       //added for testing base 64
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
       byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
       String mImageEncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
//       Log.e("TAG", "imageEncodedString: " + mImageEncodedString);
       return mImageEncodedString;
   }
```