# Android studio Image uploading error Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-storage

Hello I got an error while uploading image to Firebase. I run this same code in activity when I set up profile and there it runs perfect but when I got this in activity where you can change profile picture there come an error.

Error message

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 

ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1476211508746.jpg typ=image/jpeg }} to activity {com.samo.facedatefb/com.samo.facedatefb.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3741)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:3784)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:169)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1472)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:11
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5546)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:967)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
com.samo.facedatefb.Settings.onActivityResult (Settings.java:232)
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:6177)
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3737)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:3784)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:169)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1472)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5546)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:967)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

And here is code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.child(myEmail);
        StorageReference imageImagesRef = mStorage.child("photos/" + myEmail);

        imageRef.getName().equals(imageImagesRef.getName());    // true
        imageRef.getPath().equals(imageImagesRef.getPath());    // false


        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);

        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data2 = baos.toByteArray();

        UploadTask uploadTask = imageImagesRef.putBytes(data2);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, your image wasn't set, please try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
} else if (arrayList.get(position).equals("Change profile photo")) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
       intent.setType("image/*");
       startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is null  
 Uri uri = data.getData();
```

So before compressing bitmap check null pointer and try to find tutorial for pulling Images from Gallery. And also check for Runtime permission if your device's Android version is *marshmallow* or later.

Comment: Thanks, but how is possible that in another activity(in same app on same device at the  same time) it works? :)

Comment: @Sam Try to create bitmap from file path instead of drawing cache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804404/create-a-bitmap-drawable-from-file-path