# How to make images objects in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game where I want to replace all these white blocks and the ball (which uses a RectF collider) with images, but still keep the characteristics of the game. [image: Super Breakout]

How can I import an image like this: [image: Paddle] into the game but still keep the game mechanics? (Colliding and such).

Let me know if I should post some code I already have in order to help or anything else. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint)):

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

`dst` have to be rectF you currently been using.

For a bitmap like the sample one you have shown, `scr` can be `null` since you want to draw the entire image.

Comment: The image is a jpeg. Will it still work? Or do I have to convert to BMP?

Comment: So if my image is "image.jpg", then do I do drawBitmap(Bitmap image.jpg, Rect null, RectF collider, Paint paint)? What do I put for paint?

Comment: A [Bitmap object containing your image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804404/create-a-bitmap-drawable-from-file-path) as bitmap and `null` paint in your case