# How to get the drawable name from my image in a list view Android

Tags: android, listview, resources, imageview, drawable

Ok so I have a list view with a custom list view adapter, and each list item has an "icon". when I click the list item, I am easily able to get all the text field names such as name address etc.
I have their icon in an image view (obviously every icon is in the same id because it is getting reused in the listview). my question is how can i get the r.drawable.resource (ie pic1) when i click the list item . and pass it to my next intent (I know how to use bundle extras).

I have been searching and I can set the resource but cannot retrieve it from a imageview.
[Passing the Image in PutExtra in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210156/passing-the-image-in-putextra-in-android)

most answers I have seen are like the link above, and this assumes that you either have different ids for each image view or that you want to turn the image view into bytes(do not want to do that). does anyone know how to get the r.drawable from the image view?

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myrate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the imageView's drawable, you can set the ImageView's tag:

```
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.my_drawable);
imageView.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

And later use:

```
imageView.getTag();
```

Comment: but I am using one image view and re-using it for a listview.. that will not work...

Comment: Why won't it work? when reusing the imageView, you set its drawable. so at that same point set its tag (which will override its previous tag), and when clicking on an item, retrieving the imageView's tag will retrieve the most recent drawable id

Comment: yes, understood. so when i click item one, it takes the tag from item 10(assuming there are 10 items in the list).

Comment: Why would it take the tag from item 10?
You are using an adapter, so the views are reused, right? So every time set a new image in an imageView (once an item is displayed) you set a new tag to that image view.
So when showing item 1 with imageView 1, the tag is R.drawable.image1, and when reusing the item, for instance showing item 12 with imageView 1, the tag is R.drawable.image12.

Comment: yes i am re-using the views..i am going to try it. from what I read that when you do this, the tags just "over write". But I am not a java developer, I am JS so the concepts are completely different. Will try and I will accept you if it works thank you