# Android ListView - onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, imageview

I'm beginning in mobile application development and I want to know how to send an item from a ListView to appear in another activity; Then I can show more information about each item.

I managed to display the title and description with the following code:

MainActivity

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", txt.getText()); 
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_textView1);

Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String val = b.getString("name");
txt.setText(val);
```

but how do I set putExtra for an image to display in the next Activity ?

P.S. everything is working fine, the xml file where the item details will be shown is set.

Comment: Check these: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210156/passing-the-image-in-putextra-in-android) | [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles)

Comment: Post your layouts where image is and should travel to.

Comment: image is dynamic or static in application.

Answer (score 1):

What is the source of the image?

If a file, pass in the String to the file location.

```
bundle.putString("file-loc",fileLocation);
```

If a resource, pass in the resource.

```
bundle.putInt("resource-id",resid);
```

If it's just a bitmap, you can actually pass it directly, as a Parcelable.

```
bundle.putParcelable("bitmap",bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the ImageView's id (R.drawable.your_image) and then fetch it and show it in the ImageView of other activity